# Mysql limit left join

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, left-join

I need help applying a limit to a Left Join in a Select query.

I have a table with posts and another one with videos.
I want to select a list of posts with some filters applied, and their respective videos, limited to 25 videos per post. Now I get ALL videos for a post, which could be hundreds and which is slow!

My current Sql looks like this:

```sql
SELECT `post`.`id` AS `post_id`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`video`.`id`, ',', `video`.`timestamp`) SEPARATOR ';') AS `videos`,
       COUNT(`video`.`id`) AS `video_count`
  FROM `post`
       LEFT JOIN `video` -- Don't know how to limit these videos to 25 items
       ON `video`.`category_id` = `post`.`category_id`
       AND `video`.`file_size` > 0
       AND `video`.`timestamp_beginning`
           BETWEEN `post`.`timestamp` - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
           AND `post`.`timestamp` + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
 WHERE `post`.`author_id` = 2 AND `post`.`status` = 'active'
 GROUP BY `post`.`id`
 ORDER BY `post`.`id` DESC
 LIMIT 100,100;
```

Thank you!

Comment: @SimonMartinelli No that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: This is the classic get top N records per group problem. Pls see answers to the duplicate question for various solutions. Mysql v8 solution using window functions is quite at the bottom of the list of answers.

Comment: Which field can you use to sort the films so that the LIMIT always delivers the same ones. A LIMIT without ORDER makes no sense because the sequence is not guaranteed  -- and see answer from shadow